# AWS CloudWatch alarm on EMR using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-emr

I need to create script using boto3 which should make sending email notifications from AWS CloudWatch whenever instance in cluster is unhealthy.

I'm following [`put_metric_alarm()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.put_metric_alarm) documentation to create boto3 script, and I found that to achieve my requirement I can use `MRUnhealthyNodes` metric type. I've written a small script to create alarm which should work:

```
client.put_metric_alarm (
AlarmName='name',
AlarmDescription='alarm description',
AlarmActions=[
    'sns:arn',
],
MetricName='MRUnhealthyNodes',
Namespace='AWS/ElasticMapReduce',
Statistic='Minimum',
Dimensions=[
    {
        'Name': 'string',
        'Value': 'string'
    },
],
Period=300,  
EvaluationPeriods=287,
Threshold=1,
ComparisonOperator='GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold'
```

)

Here, I'm little confused what should be the value for:

```
Dimensions=[
    {
        'Name': 'string',
        'Value': 'string'
    },
]
```

I am new in the AWS world, so can someone help me with this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please refer to the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_Dimension.html

Comment: Hi. I've noticed that you have a lot of questions with answers, but non-was accepted. If all the answers weren't useful, that's fine. But if the answers were helpful, their acceptance is not only a good practice, but it signals others in future with similar issues to solve their own issues. Also it reduces the amount of duplicate questions.

Answer (score 1):

The valid dimensions for EMR metrics are listed in [Dimensions for Amazon EMR Metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/UsingEMR_ViewingMetrics.html):

> **JobFlowId**     - The same as cluster ID, which is the unique identifier of a cluster in the form j-XXXXXXXXXXXXX. Find this value by clicking on the cluster in the Amazon EMR console.

> **JobId**  - The identifier of a job within a cluster. You can use this to filter the metrics returned from a cluster down to those that apply to a single job within the cluster. JobId takes the form job_XXXXXXXXXXXX_XXXX.